# What is the name of this plant? (found in a rock)

Tags: botany, species-identification

I found it in Western Turkey.It was growing on a rock so what's it?

[image: sorry for picture quality]

Comment: wow so strange-looking

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have been looking into this for days, but this plant is difficult to identify without its flower. I reached out to a botanist at Dartmouth, who suggests that it is either one of two species-- a nasturtium (Tropaeoleum sp.) or a geranium (pelargonium). The leaves are what are called peltate, meaning shield-like with the stem attached directly underneath.

[image]

Source:

- Botanist at Dartmouth
- http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/48400/48426/48426_peltate_leaf.htm

---

On further research, specifically of peltate leaves, this plant looks more like Umbilicus rupestris, which is commonly found in southern Europe and grows in damp rock crevices!

Source:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbilicus_rupestris

Comment: +1 - Great job! Key here is that the plant is a succulent (neither nasturtiums nor geraniums are). The succulent nature is easier to see in the OP's picture, where the leaves are slightly wilted.